# Reading from a .txt file and looping until new line

Tags: c++11, while-loop, newline, ifstream

I am having trouble understanding the output of my very little program which should read characters from a text file until it finds a new line.
It correctly outputs the characters and stops, but I don't understand why it still outputs the newline ('\n) character in the terminal and doesn't end before getting to it.
I know that I could use getline() or find another way but I would really understand the reason behind this behaviour.
Thank you in advance!
Edo

Code:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open("../responses.txt");
    char c;
    while(c != '\n'){
        in_file.get(c);
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
D
E


Time elapsed: 000:00:000
```

The

Comment: Using uninitialized "automatic" (non-static local) variables leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Such variables values will be *indeterminate* (and seem random).

Comment: As for your problem, now is a *very* good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Both some rubber-duck debugging as well as stepping through the code line by line in a debugger should reveal the problem quite quickly.